# Duplicating the rows and relabel two of the columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the following variables, date, hour, location.

```
date=c("30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018","30/03/2018")
hour=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
location=c(China,India,France,Japan,Korea,Congo,USA)
df <- data.frame(date, hour, location)
```

I would need to duplicate this dataset many times such that I get the same 6 locations from hour 1 to hour 24 and from date 30/03/2018 to the end of the 2018 (i.e., 31/12/2018). This means that on every date, I would have hour 1 to hour 24. And each hour, I would have the exact 6 same locations.

Is there any way to simplify the coding process? I tried to use `rep` to duplicate the dataset but I face issues in the labelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  complete(location,date = seq(min(date),as.Date('2018-12-31'),by = "day"), 
                   hour = 1:24)


# A tibble: 46,536 x 3
#   location date        hour
#   <fct>    <date>     <dbl>
# 1 China    2018-03-30     1
# 2 China    2018-03-30     2
# 3 China    2018-03-30     3
# 4 China    2018-03-30     4
# 5 China    2018-03-30     5
# 6 China    2018-03-30     6
# 7 China    2018-03-30     7
# 8 China    2018-03-30     8
# 9 China    2018-03-30     9
#10 China    2018-03-30    10
# … with 46,526 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `expand.grid()`.

```
dat <- expand.grid(date=seq.Date(as.Date("2018-03-30"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by="day"),
                  location=c("China","India","France","Japan","Korea","Congo","USA"),
                  hour=1:24)
```

### Result

```
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 46536 obs. of  3 variables:
#   $ date    : Date, format: "2018-03-30" "2018-03-31" ...
# $ location: Factor w/ 7 levels "China","India",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ hour    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# - attr(*, "out.attrs")=List of 2
# ..$ dim     : Named int  277 7 24
# .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "date" "location" "hour"
# ..$ dimnames:List of 3
# .. ..$ date    : chr  "date=2018-03-30" "date=2018-03-31" "date=2018-04-01" "date=2018-04-02" ...
# .. ..$ location: chr  "location=China" "location=India" "location=France" "location=Japan" ...
# .. ..$ hour    : chr  "hour= 1" "hour= 2" "hour= 3" "hour= 4" ..
```